# Using webpack to load revealing module pattern modules and use them global and as es6 modules

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm planning on migrating a large browser application using global modules designed using the revealing module pattern design to es6 modules using webpack and babel and would like to do this incrementally.

Let's assume a global script module like this:

```
var myModule = (function(window, undefined) {
  function myMethod() {
    console.log('myMethod');
  }
  return {
    myMethod: myMethod
  };
})(window);
```

The original code base would load the module by loading it using a script tag and then use it as a global:

```
myModule.myMethod();
```

The new code should consume the module like this:

```
import myModule from './myModule.js';
```

Instead of changing all existing modules at once, I'm looking for a way to initially keep the module format but use in as global script module and a es6 module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, it's super easy in webpack. It might be me, but it took me a while to understand the webpack documentation.

This is how it is done:

## Install the exports loader

```
npm install exports-loader --save
```

## Use the exports loader

```
import myModule from 'exports?myModule!./myModule.js';
```

Where `myModule` between in the query (just before the `!`) is actually the name of the variable we assigned the return from the function to in the line `var myModule = (function(window, undefined) {`.